# Why does this sql RANK OVER() command give me all Rank 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the following query, I'm attempting to rank rows by the highest computed`WorstDerogLevel` and then lowest `RecentDerogMonths`, but it's ranking them all as 1.

```
SELECT 
            strTransID,
            strRateCode as PreviousHighRateCode,
            strRateStatusCode as TradelineRateCode,
            dateReported,
            datePreviousHigh,
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    strRateStatusCode IN ('2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                    AND
                    (
                        strRateStatusCode IN ('F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                        OR strRateStatusCode >= strRateCode 
                    )
                THEN 
                    strRateStatusCode 
                ELSE 
                    strRateCode 
            END AS WorstDerogLevel
            ,
                DateDiff(month, 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN 
                            ( 
                                dateReported >= datePreviousHigh 
                                OR datePreviousHigh is null
                            )
                            AND strRateStatusCode IN ('2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                            AND
                            (
                                strRateStatusCode IN ('F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                                OR strRateStatusCode >= strRateCode 
                            )
                        THEN 
                            dateReported 
                        ELSE 
                            datePreviousHigh 
                    END, 
                    dateTransDate) as RecentDerogMonths

            ,

        RANK() OVER   
        (
            PARTITION BY 
                DateDiff(month, 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN 
                            ( 
                                dateReported >= datePreviousHigh 
                                OR datePreviousHigh is null
                            )
                            AND strRateStatusCode IN ('2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                            AND
                            (
                                strRateStatusCode IN ('F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                                OR strRateStatusCode >= CstrRateCode 
                            )
                        THEN 
                            dateReported 
                        ELSE 
                            datePreviousHigh 
                    END, 
                    dateTransDate) 

            ORDER BY

            CASE
                WHEN 
                    strRateStatusCode IN ('2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                    AND
                    (
                        strRateStatusCode IN ('F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                        OR strRateStatusCode >= strRateCode 
                    )
                THEN 
                    strRateStatusCode 
                ELSE 
                    strRateCode 
            END desc,

                DateDiff(month, 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN 
                            ( 
                                dateReported >= datePreviousHigh 
                                OR datePreviousHigh is null
                            )
                            AND strRateStatusCode IN ('2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                            AND
                            (
                                strRateStatusCode IN ('F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'Z', '#', '$')
                                OR strRateStatusCode >= strRateCode 
                            )
                        THEN 
                            dateReported 
                        ELSE 
                            datePreviousHigh 
                    END, 
                    dateTransDate) asc

        ) AS Rank  

     FROM 
        [Customers]

    WHERE strTransID = '279579407'
```

Here is my result set 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just debug your query by adding two column `PartitionField` and `OrderField` with the expression you have on the `RANK() OVER`

There two cases where every row have `RANK = 1`

1. each rows belong to a different partition, so you have size 1 partitions.
2. all the rows in the partition have the same value, all are rank 1.

Comment: Right, that's already there, the partition by field is the same as `RecentDerogMonths` and the order by is `WorstDerogLevel` desc `RecentDerogMonths` asc, in the example above I'm hoping for 19 months to be ranked 1

Comment: Well looks like you have the second case there. All the rows in the partition have the same `WorstDerogLevel`

Comment: btw if you are `partition by  RecentDerogMonths` then there is not point in `order by RecentDerogMonths` because all the element in the partition has the same value.

Comment: Maybe if I clarify what I'm trying to do you can help me. I just want the lowest `RecentDerogMonths` with the highest `WorstDerogLevel`; I thought this would be the best way to do it.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Taking the Partition by out gives me what I want.

Comment: So if this help you solve your problem consider mark it as the answer.